# Delays when seeking with HTML5 Audio.currentTime

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I use the Audio element in my JavaScript to play a sound repeatedly in short intervals. 
IE and Chrome seem to have no delay when using currentTime, but Firefox has a very noticable delay. 
Is there a way to have Firefox to seek faster, or a better alternative to accomplish this?

I use this (sample) script:

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio("Audio.ogg");

    setInterval(function () {
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
    }, 125);
</script>
```

Comment: Since the API proposed in the answer is not fully supported by all browsers, I'll use the same audio file with multiple instances of audio elements as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 `<audio>` element has not been designed for short, intervalled, audio playback. It won't work for use cases like sound effects. `<audio>` was designed for interactive music-like playback triggered by the user.

Use [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API) for sound-effect-like playback which gives you some guarantees about the playback delays.

Comment: They should've named it `<song>` because that's pretty much all it's good for.

Comment: For completion, current compatibility amongst  all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web_Audio_API#Browser_compatibility