# Playing sound in setInterval

Tags: javascript

I have the following function

```
const a = new Audio('click.wav')


function play() {
    setInterval(() => {
        a.play();
        a.currentTime = 0;
    }, 200)

}
```

But the sound doesn't always play every time 200 milliseconds has passed, but instead sometimes play at random irregular times. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: `setInterval` does not guarantee exact times. (Instead it is only a minimum interval, as far as I know)

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657252/delays-when-seeking-with-html5-audio-currenttime) with workaround that might do.

Comment: I don't think calling `play()` each time is necessary, but I'm not sure if removing it makes it much more efficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delays when seeking with HTML5 Audio.currentTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657252/delays-when-seeking-with-html5-audio-currenttime)